# What's the preferred method for accessing "this" in a javascript enclosure?

Tags: javascript, this

I often have code like this:

```
function Object() {
}

Object.prototype.getData() {
    // THIS LINE:
    var object = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '...'
        , success: function(data) {
            object.onLoadData(data);
        }
    })
}

var o = new Object();
o.getData();
```

My question: what's the preferred paradigm for the "var object = this" bit above?  I've seen this:

```
var self = this;
```

Which looks good, and I'll probably steal this method.  What is the most common way of referring to parent object from within anonymous functions?  Are there cleverer ways of doing this?  I often find myself putting the "var object = this;" at the top of most object methods, and it seems like there might be some tricky way to avoid this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code, don't use a variable.

Use the `context:` parameter to set the `this` value in the callbacks.

```
Object.prototype.getData = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        context: this, // <-----------set the context for the callbacks
        success: function(data) {
            this.onLoadData(data);
        }
    });
};
```

---

If the question wasn't meant to only deal with `$.ajax`, then I'd use [`bind()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the `this` value to the function.

```
function successCallback(data) {
    this.onLoadData(data);
}

Object.prototype.getData = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: successCallback.bind( this );
    });
};
```

If you need to support browsers that don't have `.bind()`, then there's a shim in the docs link I provided that you can include.

Comment: I assume you're not *actually* extending `Object.prototype`, but just happened to use `Object` as the constructor name in the question.

Comment: Wow, great answer!  I think the jQuery context is exactly what I want (don't know why I've never looked at that before).  Also, .bind() is really interesting - I might use the compat code and start using that as well.  Unfortunately I've got to worry about IE7 as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/) seems to prefer `var that=this`. If you are using the ExtJs library they seem to use 
`var me= this;`. 
When it really comes down to it the name of the variable is not that important. Make sure you use something consistant with your peers and that makes sense to a novice programmer when they read it.

Answer (score 1):

in my code, I use `var that = this;` for this use case - I've also seen `self`, although for me that gets a bit confusing, as in other languages it's a reserved keyword.

There's not any other way as far as I know to get around this, but as long as you pick a keyword *only* used for this case, and use it consistently throughout your codebase, it's a pretty clean way of dealing with it. I'd avoid var names like `object`, as you'll more than likely use them elsewhere and create a confusing situation for yourself or someone maintaining your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not really (that I'm aware of). I always use `that` as the name, although it's more humorous than good practice.